# Better way SQL insert query

Tags: sql, sql-server, database

Actually, I don't know what is different the following query?

Which one is better(performance, etc...)? Btw, I use SQL Server.

Query 1 :

```
INSERT INTO PERSON (ID, NAME, ADDRESS) VALUES('001', 'Smit', 'London');
INSERT INTO PERSON (ID, NAME, ADDRESS) VALUES('002', 'Jhon', 'London');
```

Query 2 : I never saw before

```
INSERT INTO PERSON (ID, NAME, ADDRESS)
SELECT '001', 'Smit', 'London' UNION ALL
SELECT '002', 'Jhon', 'London'
```

Comment: I think that if you are getting to a point where you wish to see which syntax is better for performance, something is very wrong. As @Bill Karwin suggested, you can use the Table Value Constructor approach, but that has its limits too. If you are having issues with inserts, you might want to look at using BULK INSERTS, and maybe checking your indexing.

Comment: And you see, Query 1 is actually **2** Queries!!

Comment: Also why do you try to optimize even before using them actually? premature optimization is the root of all evil

Answer (score 5, accepted):

How about the multi-row syntax with [table value constructors](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd776382%28v=sql.105%29.aspx):

```
INSERT INTO PERSON (ID, NAME, ADDRESS) 
VALUES ('001', 'Smit', 'London'), ('002', 'Jhon', 'London');
```

Comment: I get the message what is difference from your reference. Thanks!

Comment: @Bill Karwin Could you please explain that is your query efficient than two quries in question? If yes ,why? I would like to know that.

Comment: @R.S, As far as I know, there is no significant performance difference.  But it is simpler to construct the query, so there's an improvement in developer productivity.

Comment: @BillKarwin, Is it ok the query from your answer in MSSQL Server 2005? I get error message `Incorrect syntax near ','`. I just copy and run your query. But, If I run query-1 in my post, it is ok.

Comment: I think the syntax was first supported in SQL Server 2008.